# FATAL EXCEPTION error IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android

I am quite new to coding in Android, so bear with me. I have been following this awesome tutorial and I have followed everything but I am having a problem right now with my code. Whenever I click "Register", the app crashes. When I built my app, it worked just fine. Could someone find a solution?

The error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.espina.espinasis, PID: 5040
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.
                  at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:137)
                  at com.example.espina.espinasis.activities.RegisterActivity.postDataToSQLite(RegisterActivity.java:186)
                  at com.example.espina.espinasis.activities.RegisterActivity.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:117)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

RegisterActivity.java

```
    package com.example.espina.espinasis.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.espina.espinasis.R;
import com.example.espina.espinasis.helper.InputValidation;
import com.example.espina.espinasis.model.User;
import com.example.espina.espinasis.sql.DatabaseHelper;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private final AppCompatActivity activity = RegisterActivity.this;

private NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;

private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutStudnum;
private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutLastname;
private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutFirstname;
private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutAge;
private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutSex;
private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutCourse;
private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutYearlevel;
private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutEmail;
private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutUsername;
private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutPassword;
private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutConfirmPassword;

private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextStudnum;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextLastname;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextFirstname;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextAge;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextSex;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextCourse;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextYearlevel;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextEmail;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextUsername;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextPassword;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextConfirmPassword;

private AppCompatButton appCompatButtonRegister;
private AppCompatTextView appCompatTextViewLoginLink;

private InputValidation inputValidation;
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
private User user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    initViews();
    initListeners();
    initObjects();
}

private void initViews(){
    nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);

    textInputLayoutStudnum = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutStudnum);
    textInputLayoutLastname= (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutLastname);
    textInputLayoutFirstname = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutFirstname);
    textInputLayoutAge = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutAge);
    textInputLayoutSex = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutSex);
    textInputLayoutCourse = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutCourse);
    textInputLayoutYearlevel = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutYearlevel);
    textInputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutEmail);
    textInputLayoutUsername = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutUsername);
    textInputLayoutPassword= (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutPassword);
    textInputLayoutConfirmPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutConfirmpassword);

    textInputEditTextStudnum = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextStudnum);
    textInputEditTextLastname = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextLastname);
    textInputEditTextFirstname = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextFirstname);
    textInputEditTextAge = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextAge);
    textInputEditTextSex = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextSex);
    textInputEditTextCourse = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextCourse);
    textInputEditTextYearlevel = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextYearlevel);
    textInputEditTextEmail = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextEmail);
    textInputEditTextUsername = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextUsername);
    textInputEditTextPassword = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextPassword);
    textInputEditTextConfirmPassword = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextConmfirmpassword);


    appCompatButtonRegister = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.appCompatButtonRegister);

    appCompatTextViewLoginLink = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.appCompatTextViewLoginLink);
}

private void initListeners(){
    appCompatButtonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    appCompatTextViewLoginLink.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void initObjects(){
    inputValidation = new InputValidation(activity);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
    user = new User();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.appCompatButtonRegister:
            postDataToSQLite();
            break;
        case R.id.appCompatTextViewLoginLink:
            finish();
            break;
    }
}

private void postDataToSQLite(){
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextStudnum, textInputLayoutStudnum, getString(R.string.error_message_studnum))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextLastname, textInputLayoutLastname, getString(R.string.error_message_lastname))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextFirstname, textInputLayoutFirstname, getString(R.string.error_message_firstname))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextAge, textInputLayoutAge, getString(R.string.error_message_age))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextSex, textInputLayoutSex, getString(R.string.error_message_sex))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextCourse, textInputLayoutCourse, getString(R.string.error_message_course))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextYearlevel, textInputLayoutYearlevel, getString(R.string.error_message_yearlevel))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputTextEditTextEmail(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextUsername, textInputLayoutUsername, getString(R.string.error_message_username))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextPassword, textInputLayoutPassword, getString(R.string.error_message_password))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextMatches(textInputEditTextPassword, textInputEditTextConfirmPassword,
            textInputLayoutConfirmPassword, getString(R.string.error_password_match))) {
        return;
    }

    if (!databaseHelper.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim())) {

        user.setStudnum(textInputEditTextStudnum.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setLastname(textInputEditTextLastname.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setFirstname(textInputEditTextFirstname.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setAge(textInputEditTextAge.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setSex(textInputEditTextSex.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setCourse(textInputEditTextCourse.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setYearlevel(textInputEditTextYearlevel.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setEmail(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setUsername(textInputEditTextUsername.getText().toString().trim());
        user.setPassword(textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim());

        databaseHelper.addUser(user);

        // Snack Bar to show success message that record saved successfully
        Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, getString(R.string.success_message), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        emptyInputEditText();


    } else {
        // Snack Bar to show error message that record already exists
        Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, getString(R.string.error_email_exists), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}

private void emptyInputEditText(){
    textInputEditTextStudnum.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextLastname.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextFirstname.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextAge.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextSex.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextCourse.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextYearlevel.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextEmail.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextUsername.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextPassword.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextConfirmPassword.setText(null);
}
```

activity_register_activity.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutStudnum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextStudnum"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/hint_studnum"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutLastname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextLastname"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/hint_lastname"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutFirstname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextFirstname"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/hint_firstname"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutAge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextAge"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/hint_age"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutSex"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextSex"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_sex"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutCourse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextCourse"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/hint_course"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutYearlevel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextYearlevel"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/hint_yearlevel"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextEmail"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextUsername"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/hint_username"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextPassword"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutConfirmpassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextConmfirmpassword"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/hint_confirm_password"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/appCompatButtonRegister"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:background="@color/colorTextHint"
        android:text="@string/text_register"></android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/appCompatTextViewLoginLink"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/text_already_member"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Comment: Make sure you are providing the right parent view for SnackBar.
Follow [This](https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/action.html) tutorial.

Comment: where is your snackbar

Comment: and please provide your activity_register.xml layout.

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Comment: How can I provide the right parent view for SnackBar? I really don't know.

Comment: There is no `NestedScrollView` in layout you've posted. Change the first argument in `Snackbar.make()` to pretty much any `View` that does exist in the current layout.

Comment: OK. I'll see what I can do